# SQL UPDATE command won't work with Command.Parameters.Add/AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

just discovered something strange,
If I write an SQL statement for a command like so:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE LoginTbl SET PW = @pw WHERE TwyID = @twyID";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw_txt.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twyID", TwyID.ToString());
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The SQL command will run with no exception being thrown, however it does not update the database at all.
Strangely, if I write the command without parameters:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE LoginTbl SET PW = '"+pw_txt.Text+ "' WHERE TwyID = '"+TwyID.ToString()+"'";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The SQL command runs perfectly but this time it actually updates the database!

This puzzled me some what as I am very used to using parameters in most SQL commands.

Wondering if anyone knows why the UPDATE statement particularly doesn't accept the OleDbParameters enumerator.

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: Whatever the reason, I hate to fix the issue in a non-standard approach; for various security reasons, you should not use SQL queries like that;

Comment: People, I know I shouldn't use SQL queries like I did in the second example, I was just giving an example of what works. I normally always add parameters to my commands however in this question I was outlining that you couldn't for some reason and wanted to know why! @techspider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you really don't want to use your second approach (string concatenation) as it can lead to all sorts of SQL Injection nastiness as well as issues involving parameters being passed in incorrectly.

If you are using an `OleDbConnection` or `OleDbCommand` as opposed to a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, you may want to [try not using named parameters  as they are not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used

and instead just use `?` instead. Just ensure that you add your parameters in the proper order :

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE LoginTbl SET PW = ? WHERE TwyID = ?";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw_txt.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twyID", TwyID.ToString());
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know I shouldn't use SQL statements like I did in the second example I just wanted to give an example of why it worked and why adding the parameters in the normal way I do didn't work! I have been using named parameters with OleDbCommands and they often always work just not in this case! Thanks again for the answer! @Rion Williams

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, but i tried some other way  following  using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con)) { } and instead of ? mark i used :PW  and  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PW  ", (object)PW  == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object)PW  ); so on.